# Overriding Django's ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, overriding

Because we need our ModelChoiceFields to have different (non-`__unicode__`) labels based on where they're used, I thought it would be a smart idea to override the ModelChoiceField and make it accept an extra parameter that will be called instead of label_from_instance. I could've made a subclass for every instance we need, but that's not really DRY, is it now?

My new ModelChoiceField:

```
import django.forms


class ModelChoiceField(django.forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """Subclasses Django's ModelChoiceField and adds one parameter, `obj_label`.
    This should be a callable with one argument (the current object) which
    returns a string to use as the label of that object or instance."""

    def __init__(self, obj_label=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(django.forms.ModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.obj_label = obj_label

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if self.obj_label:
            return self.label(obj)
        return super(django.forms.ModelChoiceField, self).label_from_instance(obj)
```

Seems simple and easy enough. I am only interested in the argument named `obj_label`, and pass all the rest into the `__init__` function of the ModelChoiceField. Or so I thought. Python is now complaining about `__init__` getting unexpected keyword arguments... I'm calling it like this: `nationality = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), obj_label=lambda x: x.name(), empty_label=None)`, and the error is:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  321.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  321.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  223.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  29.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/patrick/spng/src/internship/views.py" in <module>
  40. from resume.views import assemble_dict_list
File "/home/patrick/spng/src/resume/views.py" in <module>
  20. from resume.forms import (HobbyForm, LanguageForm, EducationForm,
File "/home/patrick/spng/src/resume/forms.py" in <module>
  29. class NationalityForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/patrick/spng/src/resume/forms.py" in NationalityForm
  31.     nationality = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), obj_label=lambda x: x.nationality(), empty_label=None)
File "/home/patrick/spng/src/stageplaza_ng/fields.py" in __init__
  11.         super(django.forms.ModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/patrick/spng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in __init__
  672.                                         initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /stagiaires/overzicht/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
```

It's probably something really stupid, so does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Rename your class other than `ModelChoiceField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your class other than ModelChoiceField , Please take care of the remaining logic

```
 class CustomModelChoiceField(django.forms.ModelChoiceField):
        """Subclasses Django's ModelChoiceField and adds one parameter, `obj_label`.
        This should be a callable with one argument (the current object) which
        returns a string to use as the label of that object or instance."""

        def __init__(self, obj_label=None, *args, **kwargs):
            super(CustomModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.obj_label = obj_label

        def label_from_instance(self, obj):
            if self.obj_label:
                return self.label(obj)
            return super(CustomModelChoiceField, self).label_from_instance(obj)
```

Comment: Besides renaming this, you also fixed the issue :) I had the wrong model in the super call...

Comment: Where do you implement this? forms.py? is this useful for taking a model tied to a foreign key and splitting up the display fields for a user?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it really was something stupid. I was calling the Django ModelChoiceField super in my super call. Like this: `super(django.forms.ModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. In this case it makes perfect sense that I get this exception. The ModelChoiceField super is the ChoiceField. And that class doesn't accept a keyword argument by the name `queryset`.

In fact, I should've called the super of the current class. Like this: `super(ModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. This is in the docs numerous times, but I kinda missed it this time. The correct override for the ModelChoiceField is:

```
import django.forms


class ModelChoiceField(django.forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """Subclasses Django's ModelChoiceField and adds one parameter, `obj_label`.
    This should be a callable with one argument (the current object) which
    returns a string to use as the label of that object or instance."""

    def __init__(self, obj_label=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.obj_label = obj_label

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if self.obj_label:
            return self.label(obj)
        return super(ModelChoiceField, self).label_from_instance(obj)
```

This works. But I do have to partially agree with Srinivas answer. It is clearer to rename to ModelChoiceField so it's immediately clear what's going on.